# MVC Url.Action trims the action name from url end if it is Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

How to force `Url.Action()` not trim the action name from the end of url even if the action is `Index` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the default value (`action = "Index"`) from the route definition.